# Django, how to implement a field that will be filtered in every query

Tags: django, performance, filter, indexing

I have a django model that has a field with following properties:

- Now implemented using CharField, max_length=1
- field is enumeration with 4 choices A,B,C,D
- 90% of objects will have value A, rest are evenly B,C,D
- in 90% of the queries B,C,D will be filtered out, showing only objects with A
- There will be maybe 10000-50000 objects
- Load is 95% reads with some updating and creating new objects
- This model is central to my app, so practically all pages have list or detail view.

So, 90% of the time I am filtering out the same 10% of the objects (+ whatever the query is doing above this basic filtering to get me 10-100 objects to display). What would be the best way performance wise to do this in django? (Optimizing one query might not be worth the effort, but somehow it seems wasteful to keep filtering the data same way all the time...)

- simply use filter()? Filtering A might be minor cost anyway assuming the query optimization will throw away lots of objects before differentiating between A and rest of the objects
- filter + index for the field?
- filter + index + implement the field with some specific data type to make indexing work better? What type would be ideal?
- Multi-table inheritance with dummy base + A(base), B(base), ...? Objects are handled identically, but child class tables wouldn't require filtering for that field.
- Something else?

DB is MySql with InnoDB tables. I am planning to do tests with dummy data to compare implementations, but I would appreciate any feedback and links to relevant info. View code adds User/Profile dependent things to output for each object (i.e. rating user may have given) and so I am not sure how much I can cache.

Comment: Thanks for replies! Not optimizing before it's slow makes sense. The only thing I am worried is that when things start to slow down it might be more difficult to change anything. Seeing that you are okay with simple filter + index makes me feel safer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two parts to this question: what's better in terms of efficiency, and how to write the code.

In terms of efficiency, there's no need to do anything than ensure that the database indexes include the field you'll be filtering on. You'll probably need to do at least some of that manually: use something like the django-debug-toolbar to show your queries, and create the composite indexes you need for those queries.

For the code, the best bet is to create a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/managers/) with a method that filters the A objects only:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def only_as(self):
        return self.filter(myfield='A')

...

MyModel.objects.only_as().filter(whatever=whatever)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not optimize anything until it is slow. For this size of data I'll try to use filter + index field. I don't know how many requests per seconds do you have.
If it is not fast enough, idea with separate tables looks reasonable. 
Also you can try to use a kind of cache, to split your data by key (A, B, C, D).
But my advice is to use simple solution, until it is not acceptable.